# How to integrate sonata admin bundle with a twitter bootstrap layout

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I have installed Symfony 2.2 with the SonataAdminBundle and I have a layout which supports twitter bootstrap. Now I'd like to integrate this layout into my sonata admin.

I have found [this code](https://github.com/sonata-project/sonata-bootstrap-theme), but I couldn't find any documentation. So I'd like to ask some questions:

1. How to install and configure `sonata-bootstrap-theme` in symfony
2. How to integrate twitter bootstrap layout into sonata admin bundle using or not usign `sonata-bootstrap-theme`

Comment: SonataAdminBundle uses Twitter Bootstrap by default. Isn't it enough to override templates to customize admin layout?

Comment: OK but how to do it ? I don't want to change html structure. I only want to change css with images and and js for widgets.

Comment: don't forget to install the assets (app/console assets:install)

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom css/js files in your `sonata_admin.yml`